# node.js проблемы с body-parser

Tags: node.js, express

Начал недавно изучать node.js

Вот что накодил по гайдам

```
var express = require('express');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

var app = express();
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

var artists = [
    {
        id : 1,
        name : 'Miyagi'
    },
    {
        id : 2,
        name : 'Эндшпиль'
    },
    {
        id : 3,
        name : 'Нюша'
    }
];
app.post('/artists', function (req, res) {
    console.log(req.body);
    var artist = {
        id: Date.now(),
        name: req.body.name
    };
    artists.push(artist);
    res.send(artist);
});


app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    res.end('Hello Node!');
});

app.get('/artists/:id', function (req, res) {
    console.log(req.params);
    var artist = artists.find(function (artist) {
        return artist.id === Number(req.params.id);
    });
    if (artist == null) {
        res.end('Not found artist');
    }
    res.send(artist);
});


app.get('/artists', function (req, res) {
    res.send(artists);
});
app.listen(3012, function () {
    console.log("Server is run")
});
```

Через программу Postman посылаю `POST` запросы на /artists в body в формате JSON прописываю данные и по идеи в консоли должен получить эти данные тоже в формате JSON но получаю только это `{}`

В чем проблема?

Comment: Тело запроса пустое, программа ничего не отправляет. Пустые скобочки печатает - с парсером всё нормально (он из json, кстати говоря, объект делает - сейчас выводит пустой объект).

Comment: А, ну и ответ-то напишите res.json - это ж express, он из объекта сделает JSON.stringify

Answer (score 2):

Даже не знал, что такая программка есть, но сейчас поставил и затестил - работает!

Выбрал POST

Написал URL localhost:3000/asd

Написал заголовок: Content-Type application/json

Выбрал row и в поле написал {"sfdgfhf": "vxbcbvnv"}

Нажал SEND - и console.log(red.body) на сервере таки напечатал этот объект.
Чудеса!

Всё у вас нормально в коде, проблема с запросом.

Comment: Можете подробно описать где вы написали заголовок, а то я никак не могу понять где это поле

Comment: @YuriyPo, автор ответа при необходимости самостоятельно может его удалить, не нужно убирать текст.